# PHP get correct data out of twitter array

Tags: php, twitter

I have made a script that searches for specific twitter tweets.
The problem is that it displays the whole array, and I want to display only the username and the tweet.

```
function searchHashtag($search,$count){
    $consumerKey = "xxx";
    $consumerSecret = "xxx";
    $oauthAccessToken = "xxx";
    $oauthAccessTokenSecret = "xxx";

    $twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oauthAccessToken, $oauthAccessTokenSecret);

    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
    $tweetArray = array();
    $parameters = array('q' => $search, 'result_type' => 'recent', 'count' => $count);
    $tweets = $twitter->get($url,$parameters);

    foreach($tweets->statuses as $tweet){
        $tweetArray[] = array('text'=>$tweet->text, 'username'=>$tweet->user->name);
    }
    return $tweetArray;
}

$landbouw = searchHashtag($searchlandbouw,$countlandbouw);
var_dump($landbouw);
```

I know I can use `return $tweetArray[1][1];` Then it displays only the username, but it also displays the amount of characters. Is there a easy way to display only the username and tweet, one by one?

Comment: Can I see the array structure? Print `echo "<pre>"; print_r($tweetArray); echo "</pre>";` & Paste it on pastebin.com & share the url.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EugQDvE8 this is the url

Comment: What's the problem? You can loop through array or do you have any issue for looping that array?

Comment: The problem is that i can't get the data out of that array. When I use the return function, it displays a lot more data then in the url I just send you. It displays if the context is a string or an integer, how many characters there are used etc. I just want to see the username and the tweet, nothing more, nothing less. But I am unable to do that. (I'm new to php, and i'm trying some stuff out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array structure is exactly like in `http://pastebin.com/EugQDvE8`. You can apply `for` loop in `$landbouw` to get the username and the tweet.

Just try with this.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($landbouw);$i++)
{
  echo "Tweet : ".$landbouw[$i]['text']."<br/>";
  echo "Username : ".$landbouw[$i]['username']."<br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: It is axactly like that. But it won't work. I get a blank page if I use that code. Can't see other content either.

Comment: For getting the response data (array output), Have you assigned the function call `searchHashtag(param1,param2)` to a variable?

Comment: @bbvanee why there is a ` @ the end? Typo?

Comment: I'll try it now. Does placement matter?

Comment: Still, it doesn't work. I do see my other content. but it displays nothing. And when I comment the return $tweetArray, I get a NULL, maybe that says something?

Comment: @bbvanee Just paste `var_dump($landbouw);` in pastebin.com & share.

Comment: @bbvanee Oh..I meant the response of `var_dump($landbouw);` not just `var_dump($landbouw);`!

Comment: @bbvanee `var_dump($landbouw);` seems fine. So my code supposed to be working. Just comment `var_dump($landbouw);` line & use my code & for verification I just wanna see your updated code.